# How to work with financial number formatted number in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am reading numbers in financial #s format from cells. 5,000 is financialNumberOne and 3,000 is financialNumberTwo;

```
var financialNumberOne = ss.getRange("A1").getDisplayValue();
var financialNumberTwo = ss.getRange("A2").getDisplayValue();
```

How can I convert this into number so that I can do some math with it?

```
var result = financialNumberOne + financialNumberTwo;
```

Following did not work.

```
var result = +financialNumberOne + +financialNumberTwo;
```

`Number(financialNumberOne);` //It is reading NaN

`parseInt(financialNumberOne);` //It is reading 5,000 as 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `getValue()` instead of `getDisplayValue()` because `getDisplayValue()` will just get a string like `"5,000.00"`. So the correct code for getting the numbers would be something like this.

```
var financialNumberOne = ss.getRange("A1").getValue();
var financialNumberTwo = ss.getRange("A2").getValue();
```

Comment: It helped. Thank you!

Comment: If this solved your problem please accept the answer, thanks.